# Conditional probability mass function of number of Poisson random variable given their sum values

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, density-function

We have a discrete random variable $N$, and $X_1, X_2, ... X_N$ are i.i.d Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Denote $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i$. What I want to know is:

1. If finding the conditional pmf $Prob(N=n|Y=k)$ feasible?
2. And if so how to find it.

I am well aware that $Prob(Y=k|N=n)$ is a Poisson r.v with parameter $n\lambda$

Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Edit 1: Additional information: we do not know $Prob(N=n)$.

Comment: Can you use Bayes formula to write $\Pr(N=n\mid Y=k)$ in terms of $\Pr(Y=k\mid N=n)$, $\Pr(Y=k)$ and $\Pr(N=n)$? You already know (and have included in your question) the values of 2 of the probabilities mentioned in the previous sentence. What do you know about the third?

Comment: Hi @DilipSarwate, thank you for your comment. I tried that method but we do not know $Pr(N=n)$.

Comment: Since you don't know the marginal distribution of $N,$ what information *are* you hoping to use to find the answer?

Comment: @whuber I hope there will be ideas to derive the probability of the event $Prob(N=n \cap Y=k)$ by decomposition to other equivalent events since we do know $Prob(Y=k)$.

Comment: Any such solution would be tantamount to knowing the full distribution of $N.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a problem of Bayesian inference --- if you have a prior distribution for $N$ then you can find its posterior given an observation $Y=y$.  To do this, first note that:

$$Y|N \sim \text{Pois}(N \lambda).$$

To obtain the posterior of interest, take a prior mass function $\pi_N$ and you then have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N=n|Y=y)
&= \frac{p(N=n,Y=y)}{\sum_n p(N=n,Y=y)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\text{Pois}(y|n \lambda) \cdot \pi_N(n)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text{Pois}(y|n \lambda) \cdot \pi_N(n)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n^y \cdot e^{-n \lambda} \cdot \pi_N(n)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^y \cdot e^{-n \lambda} \cdot \pi_N(n)}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer, however, I have a few questions if you don't mind.